# How to change Cell phone company logo in android

Tags: android, graphical-logo

I need to change cell phone company logo in start up android and customize that
how i can access and change it via my  app

Comment: This is during the boot sequence, far earlier than any app is actually able to run.

Comment: please answer me Instead "-1"

Comment: so you think it is impossible? if access and change boot sequence?

Comment: You would need root access and probably have to do some terminal commands to change whatever files are responsible for the splash screen and boot animation. The device would have to be rooted and you would need to know where those files live on the device, which could differ between manufacturers and devices. Besides, why would you want to do this with an app anyway? The user sees that thing for all of five seconds, then never again unless they reboot their phone, which many people don't even do.

Comment: see @HKurd we can change only BOOT ANIMATIONS ON ALL ANDROID DEVICES . but we cant change start up logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot animation is created by a set of zipped images and a small script. Full instructions are here - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1852621 - these are the instructions that I followed so I know that they work.

Now, you will face a few problems trying to do this with an app. Firstly, the default location that the OS will look for the boot animation is /system/media, but this is not the same on all versions of android, and some phone manufactures change it a different place. So to resolve this you will have to compile a list of as many possible locations and have your app check all of them for an existing animation and then replace the one that it finds.

The second problem is that all of the locations will require root privileges to copy a file into. Adding this into the manifest will allow your app to do this on rooted phones.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

Comment: how to set privileges ?

Comment: The phone will have to be rooted, and you should add the SuperUser privilage to your manifest. When the app attempts to do something that requires it, the OS will ask the user to confirm. You should then be able to do anything you like

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not with an app, that logo is part of the phone company's version of the Android OS. I believe the only way to change it is to install a different Android OS

Comment: thanks, but some apps can do it

Comment: "romtoolbox" can do it, so we can too

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant for an unrooted phone, you could do it if you had root access

Comment: @hkurd then why have you accepted that answer?

Answer (score 0):

The cellphone company logo cant usually be changed by an app on a stock, unrooted device.

The cellphone company logo is usually in the bootanimation. This is part of the OS. A rooted OS is usually required to change it. In that case, an app can change the bootanimation, and the change will be seen upon the next reboot. But it is not possible AFAIK on a stock, unrooted OS. The bootanimation is located in the system partition, and not writable by an app without rooting.

In case you mean the manufacturer logo: it is usually part of the bootloader, and cant be changed even by putting another OS on your phone. To change the bootloader, some manufacturer security must be bypassed or disabled, and you shouldnt be doing this unless you really know what youre doing - because it can so easily result in a "brick".