# How to fetch device manufacturer logo in my application in android

Tags: android

I am creating a phone hardware specific application in which I need to display user device model name, and device manufacturer logo.
Is it possible to get device manufacturer logo pro-grammatically and display it in image view, in similar to how we can get device model name & other details. If yes then how?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Cell phone company logo in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23337749/11683)

Comment: I don't want to change the company icon. I only wants to fetch it in my application, given that if it is possible.

Comment: @NileshRathod This is not a duplicate. OP wants to get the manufacturer logo, not change it. this isn't ROM customization anyways, this is an app just trying to get the boot logo

Comment: @GSerg  this is not what I have asked in my question of which you have shown the possible duplicate of.

Comment: @bhan If this gets closed, I'll vote to reopen. Anyone with common sense will see that this isn't a duplicate (the only thing in common is the logo part)

Comment: @bhan If you learn how to change the logo, surely you will know how to read it. That question links to the tutorial explaining where the logo is located and what its format is.

Comment: @LunarWatcher exactly. I only need to find out if it is even possible to get the manufacturer logo or not. If yes, then how. Its not even a duplicate question

Comment: @bhan (this is my understanding, and I'm writing this in case someone else comes along and wants to close): The proposed duplicate is basically how to change the boot logo. You want to access it and I'm assuming rendering it. Basically, changing it (in the proposed dupe) vs accessing and rendering (this question)

Comment: @LunarW The rules for closing as duplicate is that it is okay to close when the answer to the proposed duplicate also answers the new question. It is not a requirement that the questions themselves must match. You can ask something completely different and still be closed as duplicate if an existing answer happens to cover your case too. The linked article explains that the logo is in `system/media/bootanimation.zip` and describes its format, which is enough to read and display it. It also warns that manufacturers can (and do) change that as they please so there can be no generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames - library that allows to get manufacturer name and model name. For logo, you need to prepare your own database (local on phone or remote, afaik there is no any existing one ready for use).

Comment: Manufacturer name and model name can be gotten using BuildConfig. So basically, this only helps format the data in BuildConfig. And is useless in terms of answering the actual question

Comment: As far as I understand the question, author needs to get manufacturer logo. It's not present anywhere, he needs to prepare his own database